Elsa Workflow Studio use variables in expressions
i am currently trying to implement workflows with elsa version 3 using the elsa studio.
I created a variable in the workflow that has a type string and a default value. Later a want to set the variables value from http endpoint data, but for testing purposes i just want to return the variables default value to a http response.
The problem is, i can't figure out how to use the variable in the http response.
I tried different expression types for the response content and used different formattings i found online as well as some recommendations from chatgpt.
What i tried is just using the variables name put the variables name into curly braces, used context.Variables, context.Input, context.GetVariable and so on.
On most cases i get a error 500, but i was not able to output the variables value.
I also can not find anything about the expressions in the documentation.
Does anyone have a working example for this?
I also need to know how to use the expressions for an if activity.
Regards
Christian

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Please provide the expressions that you used to output the value.
